# What are the French “language buffer” words (aka “filler words”)?

Tags: traduction, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, oral

I was curious as to how to translate some "filler words" that often appear in English speech but might not translate literally into French.

For example, I might often say, "I guess," when talking about something, but not only when I want to express doubt. It could also mean being passive about the topic, or even not have much meaning – just filling in extra space. "Like" plays a similar role (but I don't hear French people saying « comme » as much).

I'd also be interested in hearing some unique French expressions that have a similar feeling but might not translate well into English. I think that these kinds of words can help bring personality into dialogue.

P.S. Is there a linguistic term for these types of words/expressions that don't add much contextually but end up in speech somehow?

Comment: This is a broad topic. Providing some in-context examples might help trigger the imagination for answers.

Comment: " 'I guess' I can come up with something. I don't 'even' know what you're looking for. This is 'sort of' what I was thinking of." How is that?

Comment: Some starters: http://www.thefrenchexperiment.com/learn-french/fillers.php

Comment: The English term is [filler words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)).

Comment: These two pages could be useful as well [here](http://www.gestionotes.fr/fiches-de-cours/17/anglais/expressions-orales-gap-fillers) and [here](http://www.gestionotes.fr/fiches-de-cours/17/anglais/expressions-orales-gap-fillers).

Comment: @Gilles: In a teaching environment most people would rather just say "gap fillers".

Comment: I have heard the word "bouche-trou"(hole closer) as a translation for "gap-filler".

Comment: There is such a thing as spoken language as distinct from written language. All these filler words don't "end up" in spoken language, they are an integral part of it. There is no point in being moralistic re spoken language. People are always saying, this is not correct French, that is not correct French. Go sit in a café in Paris and listen to people.  You won't learn all those speech patterns in grammar books. It is where the language actually lives and breathes.

Answer (score 8):

I dunno about Europe, but in Quebec the standard filler words are *tsé* (for *tu sais*) and *genre*, the latter of which is usually seen as the lower-key one.

Comment: Same in France, also, "tu vois", "en fait", "bon", "enfin" and the famous "euh".

Comment: "Quoi" is also often used as filler, at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @Fatalize True, but that's a France thing I think. You won't hear that in Québec. Like English Canadians supposedly add "eh" at the end of sentences.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Didn't know it wasn't a thing in Québec, because it's quite pervasive in France.

Comment: @hunter Are you sure about that? *Puis/pis* is not a word I've seen used that way. It shows up as a conjunction, a replacement for *et*.

Comment: @circeus i'll delete, i think my notion of "filler word" was too broad.

Comment: I have native French speaker friend who just drops the word "donc" into the conversation when it lags.

Answer (score 8):

[This Wikipedia article about filler words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)#Filler_words_in_different_languages) lists the following ones for French (emphasis mine):

> **euh** /ø/ is most common; other words used as fillers include **quoi** ("what"), **bah**, **ben** ("well"), **tu vois** ("you see"), **t'vois c'que j'veux dire?** ("you see what I mean?"), **tu sais**, **t'sais** ("you know"), and eh bien (roughly "well", as in "Well, I'm not sure"). Outside France other expressions are t'sais veux dire? ("ya know what I mean?"; Québec), or allez une fois ("go one time"; especially in Brussels, not in Wallonia). Additional filler words used by youngsters include **genre** ("kind"), **comme** ("like"), and **style** ("style"; "kind").

As a native French speaker, these all look correct to me.

---

In passing (I was looking for this when I stumbled upon this thread), it turns out a `filler (word)` would be called a `mot de remplissage` or `mot bouche-trou` in French.

Filler words can be used to articulate speech and become more fluent.

Now, undesirable filler words and expressions are called `tics de langage` [(link to the French article on the topic, with examples)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic_de_langage).

Comment: Glue all that together and you have a typical teenager's sentence.

Answer (score 4):

The standard and less classy one are "*heu*" (er), "*quoi*/*hein*" (what), "*bah/ben/bien*" (well).

But you can also use some basic one :

- "*En fait*", "*au fond*", (in fact...)
- "*En vérité*" (verily...)
- "*Alors*" (So, then)
- "*Vous savez*/*Tu sais*" (You know)
- "*Vous voyez*/*Tu vois*" (You see)
- "*Croyez-moi*/*Crois-moi*" (Believe me)
- "*hein*" (okay)
- You can always use swear words as filler in any language if you're brave enough.

Then they are the less obvious one and the list is endless. If you want political level fillers (aka *langue de bois*) you can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igwdC8N7QzA) (in french) of a full speech improvisation with only 17 base concept.

Comment: « hein ? » is also an interjection, meaning : "what ?"

Comment: Je ne pense pas que en fait, alors, etc. ont le même statut que /bah ouias/ ou hein etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Also "en vrai" appears from time to time instead of "en vérité"

Answer (score 1):

Some of these French filler words are very common and sometimes very ugly:

In the 80's and the 90's, most people used to say "*pis bon ben*" between two sentences, an ugly contraction of "puis, bon eh bien".

Nowadays, "*pis bon ben*" has mostly disappeared, but it's been replaced by another ugly terminator:  "*(...)Mais bon, voilà, quoi*".

Comment: Nanani nanana, quoi.

Answer (score 1):

"Tu vois?" has been mentioned numerous times above, but I frequently hear it as "Tu ahh" which for me is like "Tu as" - you have. However I've been re-assured by many French they are saying "Tu vois"!

I live in Lyon, France.

Answer (score 1):

Something typically parisian :
"Donc, euh... voilà quoi"
Or, simply : "quoi", at the end of the sentence : "Faut que t'arrêtes de fumer, quoi."  (You gotta quit smoking, man)